# Copy REQUEST and send to another server

Tags: php, http

A POST or GET request arrives and my code acts on it. But then it should create a new request, duplicate of the first (headers, body/content), and send it to another server exactly as it was received. What's the fastest way to do this in PHP?

Comment: http://benalman.com/code/projects/php-simple-proxy/docs/files/ba-simple-proxy-php.html YOu could try to look into that library

Comment: You may try: http://php.net/manual/en/intro.curl.php

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something like this?

```
$data = $_REQUEST;

/*
* cURL request
* 
* @param    $url     string    The url to post to 'theurlyouneedtosendto.com/m/admin'/something'
* @param    $req      string    Request type. Ex. 'POST', 'GET' or 'PUT'
* @param    $data     array     Array of data to be POSTed
* @return   $result   Obj       HTTP resonse in json decoded object
*/
function curl_req($url, $req, $data='')
    {
        $ch = curl_init($url);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST, $req);
        if (is_array($data)) {
            curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, http_build_query($data));
        }
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
        $result = curl_exec($ch);
        $result = json_decode($result);
        curl_close($ch);
        return $result;
    }


    $result = curl_req("theurlyouneedtosendto.com/path/after/url", "POST", $data);
```

Comment: What about the body/content?